# Image Masonry Grid in a Square Space

Tags: html, css, masonry

How can I make masonry grid of only 4 images that will always look like the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM3Dw.jpg)?

I need this alignment to be the same on every screen size and always form a square. Is this possible? I tried a lot of different approaches and nothing seems to work for all screen sizes.

Comment: Have you checked out [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)?

Comment: yes I tried to make it with CSS grid but I am new to this and I can't seem to make it

Comment: i did it https://codepen.io/supercica/pen/bjWezE thank you @bennett

Comment: If you were able to make it work, mark the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masonry is designed for dynamic layouts. You should probably use something more appropriate for a static grid, like CSS Grid.

Working from your own answer, I made a version a little more versatile. It uses the container width for the aspect ratio. Dependency on the device width can be limiting.

[codepen.io/joeflash/pen/wxdomE](https://codepen.io/joeflash/pen/wxdomE)

```
.grid-blocks {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is great, I did the aspect ratio in my work later but I didn't update the pen. But this is better. Thank you!